# Computing the Jacobian and Hessian of function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, jacobian, hessian-matrix

I need some help to compute the Jacobian and Hessian of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ which takes as input a vector $x$ of length $n > 0$. The other symbols can be assumed to be constant.

\begin{equation}
   f(x) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\rho_{ij}\sigma_i\sigma_j x_i x_j
\end{equation}

For the Jacobian do I just make $x_i=0$ for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f$? How does the Hessian differ once the first derivative of $x_i$ is already $0$?

Comment: 1. What are your $\sigma_k$ and $\rho_{ij}$? 2. Isn‘t your $f$ a real valued function instead of one with range in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definitions of the Hadamard $(\circ)$ and Frobenius $(:)$ products
$$\eqalign{
 B &= C\circ A  &\implies B_{ik} = C_{ik}A_{ik} \cr
 \beta &= C:A &\implies \beta = \sum_{i}\sum_{k} C_{ik}A_{ik}
}$$
Using these, you can express the function in pure matrix notation (after replacing the Greek symbols with easier to type Latin ones)
$$\eqalign{
 f &= P\circ ss^T:xx^T\cr
}$$ 
Find the differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
df &= P\circ ss^T:(dx\,x^T+x\,dx^T) \cr
 &= (P\circ ss^T+P^T\circ ss^T):dx\,x^T \cr
 &= (P\circ ss^T+P^T\circ ss^T)x:dx \cr
g=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= (P\circ ss^T+P^T\circ ss^T)x \cr
}$$
To calculate the Hessian, start with the differential of the gradient
$$\eqalign{
dg &= (P\circ ss^T+P^T\circ ss^T)\,dx \cr
H=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
 &= (P\circ ss^T+P^T\circ ss^T) \cr
 &= (P+P^T)\circ ss^T \cr
}$$
And you're done.

Comment: This is exceptionally helpful.  Do you have a good reference for this material?  I'm struggling to find accessible tutorial sources with examples for dealing with differentials.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the matrix with entries $a_{ij}=\rho_{ij}\sigma_i\sigma_j.$ Then
\begin{equation}f(x)=\langle Ax,x\rangle,
\end{equation}so
\begin{equation}f(x+h)=\langle A(x+h),x+h\rangle=\langle Ax,x\rangle +\langle A ,h\rangle+ \langle Ah,x\rangle+\langle Ah,h\rangle=f(x)+\langle (A+A^t)x,h\rangle+\langle Ah,h\rangle
\end{equation} and therefore the Hessian matrix is just $A$ itself.